# Выпадающие новости

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, popup

Необходимо реализовать блог, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку read more появлялась полная новость по центру экрана, как это показано на картинке. Как это можно реализовать без подключения js?

```css
hr {
  border: none;
  margin: 50px 0;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 1px;
}
.mnews .main-news hr {
  width: 780px;
  margin: 30px 0;
}
.mnews {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 1200px;
}
.mnews .main-news {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}
.mnews .main-news .two-news {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 780px;
  height: auto;
}
.mnews .main-news .two-news .fnews,
.mnews .main-news .two-news .snews {
  width: 380px;
}
.mnews .main-news .two-news .fnews img,
.mnews .main-news .two-news .snews img {
  width: 380px;
  height: 225px;
}
.mnews .main-news .two-news h3,
.mnews .main-news .big-news h3,
.mnews .side-news .three-news h3 {
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.mnews .main-news .two-news p,
.mnews .main-news .big-news p,
.mnews .side-news .three-news p {
  line-height: 25px;
}
.mnews .main-news .two-news a,
.mnews .main-news .big-news a,
.mnews .side-news .three-news a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
mnews .main-news .big-news {
  width: 780px;
  height: auto;
}
.mnews .main-news .big-news img {
  width: 780px;
  height: 462px;
}
.mnews .side-news .three-news {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 380px;
  height: auto;
}
.mnews .side-news .three-news img {
  width: 360px;
  height: 210px;
}
.mnews .side-news .three-news .news1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 360px;
}
.mnews .side-news .three-news {
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
}
.mnews .side-news hr {
  margin: 20px 0;
  border: none;
  width: 360px;
  height: 1px;
}
.mnews .side-news h2 {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="mnews">
  <section class="main-news">
    <section class="two-news">
      <div class="fnews">
        <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/474/black-and-white-car-vehicle-vintage-large.jpg">
        <h3>NEW BICYCLES ON THE WAY</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer finibus eros eget ornare ultricies. <a href="#">Read more</a>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="snews">
        <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/474/black-and-white-car-vehicle-vintage-large.jpg">
        <h3>TYPEOGRAPHY</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer finibus eros eget ornare ultricies. <a href="#">Read more</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <hr>

    <section class="big-news">
      <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/474/black-and-white-car-vehicle-vintage-large.jpg">
      <h3>BEST CAR SERVICES IN TOWN</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer finibus eros eget ornare ultricies. <a href="#">Read more</a>
      </p>
    </section>
    <hr>

    <section class="two-news">
      <div class="fnews">
        <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/474/black-and-white-car-vehicle-vintage-large.jpg">
        <h3>MOTORBIKES: THE FASTESTS</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer finibus eros eget ornare ultricies. <a href="#">Read more</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="snews">
        <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/474/black-and-white-car-vehicle-vintage-large.jpg">
        <h3>DRIVE SAFETY</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer finibus eros eget ornare ultricies. <a href="#">Read more</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <hr>
    <section class="big-news">
      <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/474/black-and-white-car-vehicle-vintage-large.jpg">
      <h3>ABANDONED PLACES WILL BE RESTORED</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer finibus eros eget ornare ultricies. <a href="#">Read more</a>
      </p>
    </section>
    <hr>
    <section class="two-news">
      <div class="fnews">
        <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/474/black-and-white-car-vehicle-vintage-large.jpg">
        <h3>LIBRARIES OPEN ON SUNDAY</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer finibus eros eget ornare ultricies. <a href="#">Read more</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="snews">
        <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/474/black-and-white-car-vehicle-vintage-large.jpg">
        <h3>PLACES TO VISIT</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer finibus eros eget ornare ultricies. <a href="#">Read more</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </section>

  <section class="side-news">
    <div class="three-news">
      <h2>RECENT POSTS</h2>
      <hr>
      <div class="news1">
        <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/474/black-and-white-car-vehicle-vintage-large.jpg">
        <h3>RETRO FASHION CARS</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer finibus eros eget ornare ultricies. <a href="#">Read more</a>
        </p>
      </div>

      <hr>
      <div class="news1">
        <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/474/black-and-white-car-vehicle-vintage-large.jpg">
        <h3>OLD FASHION MUSIC SHOPS</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer finibus eros eget ornare ultricies. <a href="#">Read more</a>
        </p>
      </div>

      <hr>
      <div class="news1">
        <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/474/black-and-white-car-vehicle-vintage-large.jpg">
        <h3>PHOTOGRAPHY</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer finibus eros eget ornare ultricies. <a href="#">Read more</a>
        </p>
      </div>

      <hr>
    </div>
```

[image: Как должно выглядеть]

Comment: без js сложно - проще на js или jquery

Comment: @LenovoID, сложно и глупо ... **TylerManing**, проще функцию в 5 строчек написать на JS, которая будет выставлять определённый класс соответствующему элементу по клику на «Read more», которому (классу), в свою очередь, задать нужные стили. А если делать на HTML и CSS, то это получится чистой воды говнокод — поэтому так не делают :) .

Comment: имено так я и сказал

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.modal-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 60px;
  position: relative;
  width: 160px;
}

.modal-container button {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: #446CB3;
  font-size: 22px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -5px #333;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in;
}

.modal-container .modal-backdrop {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
}

.modal-container #modal-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-container #modal-toggle:hover ~ button { background: #1E824C; }

.modal-container #modal-toggle:checked {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9;
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-container #modal-toggle:checked ~ .modal-backdrop {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 1;
}

.modal-container #modal-toggle:checked ~ .modal-backdrop .modal-content {
  background-color: #fff;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 280px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 200px);
  top: 12%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  z-index: 999;
  pointer-events: auto;
  cursor: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {

.modal-container #modal-toggle:checked ~ .modal-backdrop .modal-content { left: 0; }
}

.modal-container #modal-toggle:checked ~ .modal-backdrop .modal-content .modal-close {
  color: #666;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 7px;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-container #modal-toggle:checked ~ .modal-backdrop .modal-content .modal-close.button {
  top: initial;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  color: #fff;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.modal-container #modal-toggle:checked ~ .modal-backdrop .modal-content .modal-close.button:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #1E824C;
}

.modal-container #modal-toggle:checked ~ .modal-backdrop .modal-content .modal-close:hover { color: #333; }
```

```html
<div class="modal-container">
  <input id="modal-toggle" type="checkbox">
  <button>Click me</button>
  <div class="modal-backdrop">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <label class="modal-close" for="modal-toggle">x</label>
      <h2>Modal title</h2>
      <hr />
      <p>Modal Content</p>
      <label class="modal-close button" for="modal-toggle">Close</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Можно попробовать сделать через чекбоксы. Но проще, как написали выше, будет через jquery.

Источник http://www.cssscript.com/simple-responsive-css-modal-dialog/

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/83714)

Comment: Смысл уловил, учту.